# Using Stripe with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stripe.js

I have an angular application that uses Stripe to save customer payment card info.

I include this script in my index.html

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

this script provides a "Stripe" object that I can use like this:

```
<script> var stripe = Stripe('pk_XXXXXXXXXXX') </script>
```

the question is: How can I access the Stripe object from my angular typescript code?

Comment: This can be helpful : http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/07/05/using-stripe-payment-with-angular-2/

Comment: I've seen this solution, but I only want to do it this way as a last resort. The use of the window object is not a good practice since it might not be consistent on all browsers

Answer (score 4):

Register the type in *typings.d.ts*

```
declare var Stripe: any;
```

Instantiate a Stripe object from a Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class PaymentService {

  stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXXX');

}
```

Now you can inject this service into your components and interact with elements, but make sure to use AfterViewInit.

```
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  elements: any;

  constructor(private pmt: PaymentService) 

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // initalize elements
    this.elements = this.pmt.stripe.elements()
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, a full-stack demo in fact: https://stripe-elements.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
npm i stripe-payment-component
```

for angular typescript version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this npm: ngx-stripe-checkout

With this you can integrate stripe checkout easily in angular.

For more details : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-stripe-checkout.