# Custom Stripe Checkout form with Angular 6 and NodeJs

Tags: forms, stripe-payments, payment

Is there any way to create your own form to handle Stripe payments. (Without using the default Stripe popup?)

Comment: check as this is duplicate to the following question. [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47847606/11431018)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from popup(checkout), Stripe provides stripe elements which offer custom UI.

https://stripe.github.io/elements-examples/

To implement in Angular just add the js

> https://js.stripe.com/v3/

and use stripe variable by declaring it as any.

Example

```
   let element =  (window as any).stripe.elements();
```

For more info on how to use stripe element with angular. Please refer
https://alligator.io/angular/stripe-elements/

Comment: u can also declare the Stripe as global var. `declare var Stripe: any;`